# StanfordNLP lemmatization cannot handle -ing words

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I've been experimenting with Stanford NLP toolkit and its lemmatization capabilities. I am surprised how it lemmatize some words. For example:

```
depressing -> depressing
depressed -> depressed
depresses -> depress
```

It is not able to transform `depressing` and `depressed` into the same lemma. Simmilar happens with `confusing` and `confused`, `hopelessly` and `hopeless`. I am getting the feeling that the only thing it is able to do is remove the `s` if the word is in such form (e.g. `feels -> feel`). Is such behaviour normal for Lematizatiors in English? I would expect that they would be able to transform such variations of common words into a same lemma.

If this is normal, should I rather use stemmers? And, is there a way to use stemmers like Porter (Snowball, etc.) in StanfordNLP? There is no mention of stemmers in their documentation; however, there are some `CoreAnnotations.StemAnnotation` in the API. If not possible with StanfordNLP which stemmers do you recommend for use in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemmatization crucially depends on the part of speech of the token. Only tokens with the same part of speech are mapped to the same lemma.

In the sentence "This is confusing", `confusing` is analyzed as an adjective, and therefore it is lemmatized to `confusing`. In the sentence "I was confusing you with someone else", by contrast, `confusing` is analyzed as a verb, and is lemmatized to `confuse`.

If you want tokens with different parts of speech to be mapped to the same lemma, you can use a stemming algorithm such as [Porter Stemming](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt), which you can simply call on each token.

Comment: Yep. use stemmer if you need psedu-stems, but be very careful since the stems are not always actual words (it just uses bunch of hard-coded rules and regular expressions so it's not that smart)!

Answer (score 0):

An adding to yvespeirsman's answer:

I see that, when applying lemmatization, we should **make sure that the text keeps its punctuation**, that is, punctuation removal must come before lemmatization, since the lemmatizer takes into account type of the words (part of speech) when performing its task.

Notice the words *confuse* and *confusing* in the examples below.

With punctuation:

```
for token in nlp("This is confusing. You are confusing me."):
   print(token.lemma_)
```

Output:

```
this
be
confusing
.
-PRON-
be
confuse
-PRON-
.
```

Without punctuation:

```
for token in nlp("This is confusing You are confusing me"):
   print(token.lemma_)
```

Output:

```
this
be
confuse
-PRON-
be
confuse
-PRON-
```